# How to wrtie a XML License Line(ended with a forward slash '/') in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

I want to write a XML file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <License licenseId="" licensePath="" />
```

Some piece of my code attached here

```
    // Create a new file in D:\\ and set the encoding to UTF-8
    XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\books.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

    // Format automatically
    textWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    // Opens the document
    textWriter.WriteStartDocument();

    // Write the namespace declaration.
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("books", null);
    // Write the genre attribute.
    textWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsd", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    textWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

And now I need to write the License Line below in C#

```
<License licenseId="" licensePath="" />
```

But I don't know how to move on for I found the Line ended with the forward slash **/** .Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the WriteEndElement method will automatically take care of adding the forwards slash.

Comment: textWriter.WriteEndElement();    // Works well.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 questions about the way you're doing this:

**1**) Do you have to use a text writer? If you have access to c# 3.0 then you can use the following:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
    new XElement("Equipment",
        new XElement("License", 
            new XAttribute("licenseId", ""), 
            new XAttribute("licensePath", "")
        )
    )
);
```

2) Do you have to declare the two namespaces? It seems to me like you won't use them:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("Equipment",
        new XElement("License", 
            new XAttribute("licenseId", ""), 
            new XAttribute("licensePath", "")
        )
    )
);
```

If you're intending to write multiple `License` elements to the document, and you have them in an `Array`, `List` or some other `IEnumerable`, you can use something similar to the code below to spit them all out:

```
IEnumerable<LicenceObjects> licenses = //some code to make them;

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("Equipment",
        licenses.Select(l => 
            new XElement("License", 
                new XAttribute("licenseId", l.licenseId), 
                new XAttribute("licensePath", l.licensePath)
            )
        )
    )
);

string xmlDocumentString = doc.ToString();
```

Of course, if you don't have .NET 3.0, then this is useless to you :(

Comment: Hi Codesleuth. (+1) I must use .net 2.0 for my project currently. But your solution is very usefully for my coming study. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just proceed as you started?

```
textWriter.WriteStartElement("Licence");
textWriter.WriteAttributeString("LicenseId", "");
textWriter.WriteAttributeString("LicensePath", "");

// Other stuff
textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
textWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I must end the `license` line with the forward slash **/**. thank you.